# Conflico entre SAP y Referencia Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library en Macro Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap

Tengo un conflicto en mi macro, al añadir la referencia de Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library en VBA, todas las demás macros relacionadas con SAP no funcionan en la línea de código de acceso a la transacción.

¿Alguno sabe a qué puede ser debido?

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```vb
'Rutina de inicio, llama a SAP
 If Not IsObject(Appli) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set Appli = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = Appli.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
'Elegimos la transación esta es la línea donde me da el ERROR
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ME5A"
```

El error que recibo es:

> Error '438' en tiempo de ejecución: El objeto no admite esta propiedad o método.

Comment: Puedes añadir la linea que te falla?

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo el código de error

Comment: muy bien, y qué error te lanza?

Comment: Error '438' en tiempo de ejecución: El objeto no admite esta propiedad o método

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los motivos por los cuales puede estar fallando es que el nombre de las variables podría entrar en conflicto con otras variables de VBA de Outlook.

Mi sugerencia:

```vb
 Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
 Set Appli = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
 Set SAPConnection = Appli.Children(0)
 Set SAPsession = SAPConnection.Children(0)
 SAPsession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ME5A"
```

Comment: Vamos a esperar en lugar de Pablos resultado de la prueba. ;-)

Comment: Parece ser que efectivamente era un conflicto con otras variables de VBA de Outlook.

Comment: Gracias a Mariano para el diseño gramatical perfecta. ;-)